# Mapping json column keys onto matching column values from 2nd table

Tags: sql, json, database, postgresql

I have a table `A`, where `data` is a json column, and `timestamp` is a timestamp with timezone column:

| timestamp | data |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-08-29 13:00:00-04 | { "a_123":{ "temp":85, "uv":5, "rain":0 }, "b_123":{ "temp":85, "uv":5, "rain":0 } } |
| 2023-08-29 14:00:00-04 | { "a_123":{ "temp":70, "uv" 1:, 1"rain":5 }, "b_123":{ "temp":73, "uv":1, "rain":7 } } |
| 2023-08-29 15:00:00-04 | { "a_123":{ "temp":83, "uv":4, "rain":1 }, "b_123":{ "temp":87, "uv":7, "rain":0 } } |

I have a second table `B`:

| id | location | elevation | tag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a_123 | 04662 | 155m | blue |
| b_123 | 84003 | 15m | yellow |

I can map individual data column keys eg. `a_123` from table `A` onto the matching `id` from table `B` but in my case the data column keys from table `A` are dynamic.

How would I produce a table where the nested timestamp data is mapped to each `id` as follows, from the sample data provided above? Thanks for any help/docs.

| id | location | elevation | tag | data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a_123 | 04662 | 155m | blue | { "2023-08-29 13:00:00-04":{ "temp":85, "uv":5, "rain":0 }, "2023-08-29 14:00:00-04":{ "temp":70, "uv":1, "rain":5 }, "2023-08-29 15:00:00-04":{ "temp":83, "uv":4, "rain":1 } } |
| b123 | 84003 | 15m | yellow | { "2023-08-29 13:00:00-04":{ "temp":85, "uv":5, "rain":0 }, "2023-08-29 14:00:00-04":{ "temp":73, "uv":1, "rain":7 }, "2023-08-29 15:00:00-04":{ "temp":87, "uv":7, "rain":0 } } |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `jsonb_each` with successive `cross join`s:

```
select t.id, t.location, t.elevation, t.tag, jsonb_object_agg(t1.timestamp, v.value)
from tableb t cross join tablea t1 cross join jsonb_each(t1.data) v
where t.id = v.key
group by t.id, t.location, t.elevation, t.tag
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rRvk-zfy)

Comment: Thank you kindly.  Coming from mainly nosql background so would not have thought of cross join.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   b
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT jsonb_object_agg(a.timestamp, a.data -> b.id)
   FROM   a
   WHERE  a.data ? b.id  -- optional, but faster
   ) a ON true
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JWHyAoLL)

1. Extract the object fields from `a.data` with `b.id` as key value using the basic [`json` operator `->`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE). (This way we don't process unrelated keys that also might be there.)
2. Build new objects with `a.timestamp` as key and the extracted value from step *1.*, and aggregate them into a nesting object in one step with [`json_object_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html).
3. Do all of this in a `LATERAL` join. `LEFT JOIN LATERAL ... ON true`, to be precise. See:

   - [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

   Aggregating in a lateral subquery keeps you from having to aggregate the outer table `b` as well, which would be unnecessary cost and complication.
4. The [operator `?`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) in the optional `WHERE a.data ? b.id` excludes rows without matching top-level key early. Only works for `jsonb`. Uses an index efficiently - if only a small fraction of rows in table `A` matches.

You said "json", but I'll assume the more commonly used `jsonb`. The query works for `json`, too, with the respective function `json_object_agg()`, and without the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Tested this & ajax124's answer, their method using the cross join is faster for my use case, applying it to about 90,000 rows the results returned in 2.47s. Using the left join method returned the same results in 70.65s. My JSON data is much denser/larger than my example which may have something to do with that. Thank you for the explanation and the time to answer.

Comment: If most or all rows in table `A` qualify, and not much else is in the json documents - like seems to be the case - then simply unnesting all - like Ajax' query does - will be cheaper.